# Controller (Spring MVC) для zTree

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

Хочу чтобы у меня в проекте было динамическое дерево http://www.ztree.me/v3/demo.php#_108 . Не могу понять как это сделать на Spring MVC(java).

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.